# Inserting data into multiple columns in MySQL table from python

Tags: python, mysql

For some reason, I'm unable to insert data into multiple columns in mysql table. As soon as I insert into the first column (anyone column), I find it difficult to insert into other columns.
I noticed that after inserting into the first column, in the second column, the insertion starts from the point where it ended in the first column, but on the second. I tried inserting on a third column but no insertion took place.

See my code below:

```
week1=xrange(1,101,1) #for column1
week2=xrange(1,101,1)#for column2

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO stud(classID) VALUES(%s)", [(x,) for x in week1])

db.commit()
```

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Which MySQL library you are using? Have you read [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/)?

Comment: Hi @Tupteq, I make use of MySQL-python 1,2,3 connector. I haven't read about the PEP.

Comment: Then I think you should start from reading PEP. It should answer to this question and to many other you'll have.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but please i'll need to get this done very quickly. Do you have any other suggestions other than reading the pep?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to produce lists with two columns; if your two columns are coming from two separate iterables, use `zip()` to join them:

```
week1 = xrange(1, 101) #for column1
week2 = xrange(1, 101) #for column2

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO stud (classID, othercolumn) VALUES(%s, %s)", zip(week1, week2))
db.commit()
```

`zip(week1, week2)` produces a sequence of tuples; each a pair of values taken from both input sequences: `[(week1[0], week2[0]), (week1[1], week2[1]), ...]`.

Comment: @Tiger1: Glad to have been of help!

Comment: One more question before you go, how can I extend the row limit beyond 1000?

Comment: What database adapter are you using? I'm not sure what limit this is; number of columns or number of rows for `executemany()`? This may be a database-specific limit.

Comment: Its the row limit i'm talking about, mine is fixed at 1000 and I need more than that.

Comment: @Tiger1: Sorry, I don't know. You can always run your insertions in matches if you cannot work around that.